# Converting/compiling Python code to readable C

Tags: python, c, code-generation

I'm writing real-time software in C for a specialized hardware target (with its own C compiler).

Up until now I've used Matlab for the algorithm development and then used Matlab's code generation feature to convert the Matlab code to C, at which point i'd integrate the generated code into the real-time software.

But I'd really like to move away from Matlab to Python for the algorithm development, which means i need a way to convert/compile Python code to **human readable and maintainable** C code. So for example, Cython is not an option, since it produces code which is not human readable, let alone maintainable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does the C code need to be human readable, when all development is done in Python?

Comment: Don't.  Either write maintainable C code, or write maintainable Python code and compile it to C as part of your deployment process, accepting that the generated C code is for machines and not humans.  Machines are not as good at writing human-readable code as humans are at writing machine-readable code.  If they were, we'd all be out of jobs, and probably also being hunted by terminators.

Comment: Moreover, Python isn't designed in such a way to make it _possible_ to transpile to good C. There are other languages that are -- [the V language](https://www.v-lang.org/) comes to mind -- but it needs to be a goal when the language is first being designed, which was very much not the case for Python (too much dynamicism or metaprogramming support and conversion to idiomatic\ C becomes impossible)

Comment: ...if your goal in getting to C is performance, by contrast, think about using [Julia](https://julialang.org/), which is specifically built for heavy math work, comparably easy-to-read to Python, and in some cases faster than C -- see https://julialang.org/benchmarks/.

Comment: @Sören not all the development is done in python, just the core algorithm. so for example, all the program workflow, io, etc. are in C

Comment: @user1410541, then why do you need to compile to C? You can just use libpython to call Python from C if that's the only problem.

Comment: @Samwise there are numerous python libraries I'd like to take advantage of, on one hand, and on the other hand there is further development that has to be doe in C.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy like i mentioned, the target platform is a specialized real-time hardware. e.g. bare metal (no OS) etc...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy namely, python (or anything else other the C) is not an option

Comment: if you have already used matlab to generate readable C, why don't you just use that C code going forward?  i.e. maintain it in C and don't even use python

Comment: @ekrall good question - two main reasons - (1) there are numerous python libraries I'd like to take advantage of, and (2) it'll save me a lot of money on Matlab licenses...

Comment: In that case, have you thought about creating an executable from the Python script and integrating that?  The step of wanting to auto-generate "readable" C is where you are going to get stuck

Comment: @ekrall like i mentioned,  the target platform is a specialized real-time hardware, so i can't do anything "fancy" like creating an executable from the Python code... the ONLY thing that i can compile for that hardware is C.

Comment: then I think your only options are do all the development in C in the first place, or live with the code that gets produced by something like Cython

Comment: @ekrall yup - that was pretty much my conclusion as well... hoped i had missed something.

Comment: Python is written in C -- if you can compile C, you should be able to compile the Python interpreter, or at least a subset like TinyPython. I'm not saying there won't be any porting work needed (especially if you don't have OS amenities like a filesystem), but you can hire that out pretty easily; I was doing porting and packaging for embedded systems more than 20 years ago.

Comment: I think the question has merit. I would look into combining LLVM's MLIR backend "emitc" and see if it can be combined with e.g. numba.